# Want to re-run the classes having failed methods after the suite is completely executed using TestNG

Tags: testng, execution, suite

Can anyone help me to find a way so that i can execute all the test classes having failures together at the end after execution of the suite once.

like if I have

```
<test name="Transaction Module" preserve-order="true" >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.uniteller.tests.ABC" />
        <class name="com.uniteller.tests.XYZ" />
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Beneficiary Module" preserve-order="true" >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.uniteller.tests.PQR" />
        <class name="com.uniteller.tests.LMN" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

And There are failures in class ABC and LMN, so I want to execute these two classes again after the suite is executed once.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute all failed tests after suite use testng-failed.xml see [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#rerunning):

> 5.12 - Rerunning failed tests
>
> Every time tests fail in a suite, TestNG creates a file called testng-failed.xml in the output directory. This XML file contains the necessary information to rerun only these methods that failed, allowing you to quickly reproduce the failures without having to run the entirety of your tests.  Therefore, a typical session would look like this:
>
> ```
> java -classpath testng.jar;%CLASSPATH% org.testng.TestNG -d test-outputs testng.xml
> java -classpath testng.jar;%CLASSPATH% org.testng.TestNG -d test-outputs test-outputs\testng-failed.xml
> ```
>
> Note that testng-failed.xml will contain all the necessary dependent methods so that you are guaranteed to run the methods that failed without any SKIP failures.
>
> Sometimes, you might want TestNG to automatically retry a test whenever it fails. In those situations, you can use a retry analyzer. When you bind a retry analyzer to a test, TestNG automatically invokes the retry analyzer to determine if TestNG can retry a test case again in an attempt to see if the test that just fails now passes. Here is how you use a retry analyzer:
>
> 1. Build an implementation of the interface org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer
> 2. Bind this implementation to the @Test annotation for e.g., @Test(retryAnalyzer = LocalRetry.class)
>
> Following is a sample implementation of the retry analyzer that retries a test for a maximum of three times.
>
> ```
> import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
> import org.testng.ITestResult;
>
> public class MyRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer {
>
>   private int retryCount = 0;
>   private static final int maxRetryCount = 3;
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
>     if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
>       retryCount++;
>       return true;
>     }
>     return false;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> import org.testng.Assert;
> import org.testng.annotations.Test;
>
> public class TestclassSample {
>   @Test(retryAnalyzer = MyRetry.class)
>   public void test2() {
>     Assert.fail();
>   }
> }
> ```